# on remote pc, am not able to open rviz

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, ros

am not able to see rviz in my remote PC using vnc viewer, but am able see and launch various other commands.log:

```
[ INFO] [1551755630.412826739]: rviz version 1.12.16
[ INFO] [1551755630.412874115]: compiled against Qt version 5.5.1
[ INFO] [1551755630.412886720]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0            (Ghadamon)
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 148 (Unknown), sequence: 167, resource    id: 0, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 20
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe VNC works at a very low level and forward display directly to remote computer.  I have generally found it easier to remotely login using `ssh -X` and then running rviz, which gets the display to the remote machine.
Alternatively teamviewer is quite stable too.